# Looping though a list of sheets

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am trying to loop through a list of (randomly named) worksheets and for each calculate the last row and then loop though all the rows and execute some code.

I've tried the code below but I'm getting `Invalid Procedure Call or Argument`. I've modified in all kinds of ways but it's driving me crazy...thank you in advance.

```
Sub myloop()

    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim WsArray As Variant
    Dim rcount As Integer


WsArray = Array("mysheet1", "mysheet2", "mysheet3", "mysheet4")

With ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In WsArray

        rcount = .Worksheets(ws).Cells("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 1 To rcount

            If ...Then

            End If
        Next

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what language that is but I think might be VBA for Excel. Whatever it is, you should tag this question with the language to help folks find it.  There won't be anyone who is searching StackOverflow to answer questions on "loops" (which at the moment is the only tag on this question).

Comment: If an answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 1):

@Santosh makes a great point about finding the last row. As for the original question, in any `Workbook` there exists a `Worksheets` collection that might actually be easier to loop through depending on your structure:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    'match worksheet names if necessary using ws.Name...
    '
    'do other cool stuff...
    '
    'wrap it all up
Next ws
```

Comment: +1: I prefer that syntax for looping through worksheets

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of going to cell A1 and going down to find the last row its better to go to last cell (rows.count) and then go up.

```
Sub myloop()

    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim WsArray As Variant
    Dim rcount As Integer


    WsArray = Array("mysheet1", "mysheet2", "mysheet3", "mysheet4")

    With ThisWorkbook

        For Each ws In WsArray

           With .Worksheets(ws)
             rcount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With

            For i = 1 To rcount

                'If .. Then


                End If
            Next

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i would declare i and rcount as Long